# GCP: Cloud Shell: gcloud sql instances create: returns HTTPError 503

Tags: gcloud, http-status-code-503, google-cloud-platform

I've been trying to create a new SQL instance on Google Cloud Platform with the below INPUT command from the Cloud Shell but am continuously returned with the same Error. Could someone direct me to check the status of the connection or my account?

INPUT:

```
~$    gcloud sql instances create NAME-sql --assign-ip --tier D1 --region asia-northeast1 --gce-zone asia-northeast1-c
```

OUTPUT:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.create) HTTPError 503: Service temporarily unavailable. This is most likely a transient error. Please retry.
```

I'm not trying to solve the error but rather would like to find out why i'm getting a 503 and what I can do to rectify this unavailablility.

Other commands such as

```
gcloud sql instance list
```

are working fine...
I was able to create the sql instance from the web GUI interface. it's just the cloud command line that isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.5.4), HTTP 503 indicates:

> The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary
> overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is that this is
> a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some delay.

If you wait a while and try again, it should work.